# Normalization of inputs of a feedforward Neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, normalization, feed-forward

Let's say I have a mxn matrix of different features of a time series signal (column 1 represents linear regression of the last n samples, column 2 represents the average of the last n samples, column 3 represents the local max values of a different time series but correlated signal, etc). How should I normalize these inputs? All the inputs fall into different categories, so they have a different range. One ranges from 0,1, the other ranges from -5 to 50, etc etc.

**Should I normalize the WHOLE matrix? Or should I normalize each set of inputs one by one individually?**

Note: I usually use mapminmax function from MATLAB for the normalization.

Comment: So, what must be the range for the columns in expected output?

Comment: The target is a binary output... So I will treat the output as a probability. Specifically the output is -1 or 1. So the range of the inputs should be between -1 and 1. But I am still unsure if I should normalize the WHOLE matrix, or each vector one by one... Or are those two equivalent?

Comment: If you are looking for a range `[-1,1]` along each column, just do `(round(mapminmax(A.',0,1).')*2)-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalise each vector/column of your matrix individually, they represent different data types and shouldn't be mixed up together.

You could for example transpose your matrix to have your 3 different data types in the rows instead of in the columns of your matrix and still use mapminmax:

```
A = [0 0.1 -5; 0.2 0.3 50; 0.8 0.8 10; 0.7 0.9 20]; 
A =
         0    0.1000   -5.0000
    0.2000    0.3000   50.0000
    0.8000    0.8000   10.0000
    0.7000    0.9000   20.0000

B = mapminmax(A')
B =
   -1.0000   -0.5000    1.0000    0.7500
   -1.0000   -0.5000    0.7500    1.0000
   -1.0000    1.0000   -0.4545   -0.0909
```

Comment: So by transposing the matrix the function mapminmax will automatically normalize each vector individually and not mix the data for normalization?

Comment: yes, it says so in the [matlab documentation for mapminmax](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html). I quickly checked it for the small example above.

Comment: I see... Ok cool thanks. P.S Since Matlab automatically calls mapminmax when creating a net with feedforward, then I don't need to manually normalize the inputs right? (It's just a matter of transposing the matrix basically?)

Comment: @LuisCruz yes I'd say. If the manual says it calls mapminmax with the same input you give.

Answer (score 1):

You should normalize each **feature** independently.

> column 1 represents linear regression of the last n samples, column 2 represents the average of the last n samples, column 3 represents the local max values of a different time series but correlated signal, etc

I can't say for sure about your particular problem, but generally, you should normalize each feature independently. So normalize column 1, then column 2 etc.

> Should I normalize the WHOLE matrix? Or should I normalize each set of inputs one by one individually?

I'm not sure what you mean here. What is an input? If by that you mean an instance (a row of your matrix), then no, you should not normalize rows individually, but columns.

I don't know how you would do this in Matlab, but I took your question more as a theoretical one than an implementation one.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a theoretical question. And awesome, so I will normalize them independently then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a range of `[0,1]` for all the columns that normalized within each column, you can use [`mapminmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html) like so (assuming `A` as the 2D input array) -

```
out = mapminmax(A.',0,1).'
```

You can also use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for the same output, like so -

```
Aoffsetted = bsxfun(@minus,A,min(A,[],1))
out = bsxfun(@rdivide,Aoffsetted,max(Aoffsetted,[],1))
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     3     7     4     2     7
     1     3     4     5     7
     1     9     7     5     3
     8     1     8     6     7
>> mapminmax(A.',0,1).'
ans =
      0.28571         0.75            0            0            1
            0         0.25            0         0.75            1
            0            1         0.75         0.75            0
            1            0            1            1            1
>> Aoffsetted = bsxfun(@minus,A,min(A,[],1));
>> bsxfun(@rdivide,Aoffsetted,max(Aoffsetted,[],1))
ans =
      0.28571         0.75            0            0            1
            0         0.25            0         0.75            1
            0            1         0.75         0.75            0
            1            0            1            1            1
```

Comment: So the recommended way is to normalize the whole matrix? Not each vector (column) one by one?

Comment: @LuisCruz Ah sorry, I am not familiar with `Neural network`. So, I am not sure what's recommended for your NN work, I can only help in getting you an expected output.